# How to solve n-lateration problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Given a 3D coordinates of a set of $n$ points: $A_1(x_1,y_1,z_1), A_2(x_2,y_2,z_2), ... A_n(x_n,y_n,z_n)$. Also, $\forall i \in [1..n]$ we know some **approximate** distance $l_i$, from point $A_i$ to point $L$, and it is known that $l_n$ **could have** some unknown, but relatively small **error**. I mean $\frac{l_n+|A_nL|}{|A_nL|} \approx 1$, ratio could be equal to 1 but this is not guranteed, and there is no way to measure error.
The task is to find coordinates of $L(x,y,z)$ with least possible absolute error. There is no way to measure error.

How could i solve this "$n$-radar location", or "$n$-lateration" problem?

PS. I thought following analytical geometry algorithm. 
for each sphere pair we could

1. draw a line segment, connecting their centres,
2. find a point on that line, which dissects segment in a ratio of their radiuses.
3. draw a plane through that point and perpendicular to that line. 
   then several cases, i even dont know now how to determine.

   - In ideal case (when all lenghts were measured without an error) that planes will intersect in a single point. Well, $L$ is found! (in this case we could use spheres equation system and it will have single root)
   - Otherwise this could be concave 2d polygon or 3d mesh. and we have somehow to find its.. center of mass, assuming that mesh is a solid body having uniform density.

I feel, it has to do something with matrix lineal algebra. where $A$ is $3 * n$ matrix and $l$ is a vector of length $n$. And solution is known and is a kind of matrix-vector magic, eg multiply-divide-.... giving one and exactly one point in result. You just have to know it or not know. I dont, so am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the point of coordinates $(X,Y,Z)$, you need to consider minimizing
$$SSQ=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sqrt{(x_i-X)^2+(y_i-Y)^2+(z_i-Z)^2}-d_i\right)^2$$ which would imply nonlinear regression and, for sure, good initial estimates.

Almost as said in answers, in a first step, consider the $n$ equations
$$f_i=(x_i-X)^2+(y_i-Y)^2+(z_i-Z)^2-d^2_i$$ from which you can generate $\color{red}{\large\frac {n(n-1)}2}$ equations
$$g_{ij}=f_i-f_j=2(x_j-x_i)X+2(y_j-y_i)Y+2(z_j-z_i)Z+A_{ij}$$ where 
$$A_{ij}=(x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2-d_i^2)-(x_j^2+y_j^2+z_j^2-d_j^2)$$ that you can easily solve using multilinear regression (or matrix calculations). This will give you *estimates* of $(X,Y,Z)$.

But, to polish the solution, you need, in the final step, to consider the real model $$d=\sqrt{(x-X)^2+(y-Y)^2+(z-Z)^2}$$ and minimize $SSQ$.

For illustration purposes, I used the following data
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & d \\
 123 & 234 & 456 & 4260 \\
 234 & 456 & 789 & 4100 \\
 345 & 678 & 901 & 3980 \\
 456 & 789 & 12 & 3980 \\
 567 & 890 & 123 & 3850 \\
 789 & 12 & 345 & 3670 \\
 890 & 123 & 456 & 3530
\end{array}
\right)$$ The first step leads to $$X=4286.6\qquad  Y=765.1 \qquad  Z= 954.9$$ Doing the final step, what we get is quite different
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error}  \\
 X & 4319.82 & 3.25  \\
 Y & 780.21 & 15.97  \\
 Z & 970.73 & 17.44  \\
\end{array}$$ while the data were generated using $X=4321$, $Y=765$, $Z=980$ and the distances were rounded to the next ten.

Reporting the distances computed from the model
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
x & y & z & d & d_{calc}\\
 123 & 234 & 456 & 4260 & 4263.41 \\
 234 & 456 & 789 & 4100 & 4102.69 \\
 345 & 678 & 901 & 3980 & 3976.75 \\
 456 & 789 & 12 & 3980 & 3981.00 \\
 567 & 890 & 123 & 3850 & 3848.95 \\
 789 & 12 & 345 & 3670 & 3667.21 \\
 890 & 123 & 456 & 3530 & 3529.95
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we consider the specific case where the four points would be located at the vertices of a regular tethraedron, the data would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & d \\
 a & 0 & -\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} & d_1 \\
 -a & 0 & -\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} & d_2 \\
 0 & a & \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} & d_3 \\
 0 & -a & \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} & d_4
\end{array}
\right)$$ and the first step would lead to 
$$X=\frac{d_2^2-d_1^2}{4a} \qquad Y=\frac{d_4^2-d_3^2}{4a} \qquad Z=\frac{d_1^2+d_2^2-d_3^2-d_4^2}{4a\sqrt 2} $$

Comment: thanks for your great detailed reply!

Comment: i more question.could we add some simplifications or derive something if we have a special case - 4 points, which are located at vertices of a regular tethraedron?

Comment: @xakepp35. Have a look to my edit.

Comment: much more detailed and leading directly to implementation. top quality!

Answer (score 1):

To determine the coordinate $(x,y,z)$ of the point $L$, we have $n$ equations

$$(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2+(z-z_i)^2=l_i^2(1+2\epsilon_i),$$

with $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. We may expand the squares to obtain

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-2xx_i-2yy_i-2zz_i+(x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2-l_i^2)=2l_i^2\epsilon_i.$$

Your proposed method is equivalent to using two such equations at a time and subtracting one from the other to cancel $\,x^2+y^2+z^2\,$ and obtain a linear equation for $x,y,z\,$ (which is a plane in $\mbox{3D}$). But this either correlates the errors of different planes or not fully using the data (by obtaining only $n/2\,$ planes). An improvement of the method is to consider $x^2+y^2+z^2=A$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ as $4$ independent variables. Then we have $n$ linear equations for them

$$A-2xx_i-2yy_i-2zz_i+(x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2-l_i^2)=2l_i^2\epsilon_i,$$

with $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. If $n\geq 4$, we can find a least-square solution $(A^*,x^*,y^*,z^*)$ using linear algebra, which minimizes $\sum_i\epsilon_i^2$. Then $A^*\,$ and $\,(x^*)^2+(y^*)^2+(z^*)^2\,$ will be within error, since their true values would be exactly equal. We may then locally linearize the nonlinear constraint $\,A=x^2+y^2+z^2\,$ around $(A^*,x^*,y^*,z^*)$ using $\,dA=2xdx+2ydy+2zdz\,$ to obtain

$$A=A^*+2x^*(x-x^*)+2y^*(y-y^*)+2z^*(z-z^*).$$

Then we have $n+1$ linear equations for $4$ unknowns $A,x,y,z$. The constraint equation has no error (except the nonlinearity of order $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$). We may use it to cancel all of the $A$'s in the other $n$ equations with errors and do a least-square fitting again to obtain $x,y,z$.

Comment: thanks for good explanation i am starting to get the point. what is "find a least-square solution (A∗,x∗,y∗,z∗) using linear algebra, which minimizes ∑iϵ2i∑iϵi2"? hot to do this? where to read?

Comment: You can read http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0403.pdf, or look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462472/linearising-a-cubic-function/, where I gave a derivation of the formula in a similar situation.